# How to perform vertical scroll on android app using Appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

http://www.dropmocks.com/mHBona. I want to select hours and mins in the android app. Hours and mins are in android.view.View class. Can someone help how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `driver.swipe(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy, int duration)` where x and y stand for the coordinates on the screen.
Try to adjust the coordinates to match your action.